# Python functools.partial - How to apply it to a class method with the static decorator

Tags: python, static-methods, python-decorators, functools

I know there must be a way to do this.  But I'm getting the error "TypeError: the first argument must be callable".

What could I do differently to make this work?

```
class FaxMachine(object):
    MODEL_NO = '100'

    @staticmethod
    def load_fax(fax, error=''):
        # send fax here

    fail_fax = functools.partial(load_fax, error='PC LOAD LETTER')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`staticmethod` objects are not callable. They're [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor) that keep references to original functions in their `__func__` attributes.

So the following works:

```
# Note: apply staticmethod again
fail_fax = staticmethod(partial(load_fax.__func__, error='PC LOAD LETTER'))
```

You could also define a helper function in the class namespace, to avoid unnecessary attribute lookups:

```
def _load_fax(fax, error=''):
    # ...

# _load_fax is an ordinary function
load_fax = staticmethod(_load_fax)
fail_fax = staticmethod(partial(_load_fax, error='PC LOAD LETTER'))
```

Though the correct Python 3.4+ solution is to use the [`partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod), which was designed to work with descriptors:

```
fail_fax = partialmethod(load_fax, error='PC LOAD LETTER')
```

Answer (score 3):

methods and functions behave differently when "called": functions are called directly by using `__call__` while methods (not generally methods, I think only descriptors) are called by `__get__`.

Therefore the `functools`-module contains another `partial` for methods: [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod):

```
functools.partialmethod(load_fax, error='PC LOAD LETTER')
```

The official documentation contains a very good explanation especially in regard to `staticmethod`.

Comment: Is that only in Python 3?

Comment: It seems like [``functools.partialmethod``](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) was introduced in python 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a smarter way to do it but this seems to work fine.

```
import functools

class FaxMachine(object):
    MODEL_NO = '100'

    @staticmethod
    def load_fax(fax, error=''):
        print error or fax

FaxMachine.fail_fax = functools.partial(FaxMachine.load_fax, error='PC LOAD LETTER')

f = FaxMachine()
f.load_fax('hi')
f.fail_fax('hi')
```